# How to implement consumption peer to peer with sarama library?

Tags: go, apache-kafka, sarama

Now, I try to use Shopify/sarama library(kafka go client) to implement multiple consumers in the same consumer group, and I found several consumer groups with same client did not work.

I have the following testing:
Suppose the topic have 3 partitions, and the group Id is "groupId":
**1. TEST1**
(1)

```golang
newClient, err := sarama.NewClient(brokerList, &cfg)
```

(2)

```golang
group1, err := sarama.NewConsumerGroupFromClient(groupId, newClient)  
group2, err := sarama.NewConsumerGroupFromClient(groupId, newClient)
group3, err := sarama.NewConsumerGroupFromClient(groupId, newClient)
```

The testing is try to use a kakfa client(newClient) to create multiple groups, and the program will block one group, and the other two groups will not response, it seems to block the following code:
`group.Consume(ctx, strings.Split(topics, ","), consumer)`
and then a moment later, the program rebalance (setup/clean up) repeatly, the result is that the consumer consumed all partitions, not each consumer consume per partition.

**2. TEST2**
(1)

```golang
newClient1, err := sarama.NewClient(brokerList, &cfg)
group1, err := sarama.NewConsumerGroupFromClient(groupId, newClient1)
```

(2)

```golang
newClient2, err := sarama.NewClient(brokerList, &cfg)
group2, err := sarama.NewConsumerGroupFromClient(groupId, newClient2)
```

(3)

```golang
newClient3, err := sarama.NewClient(brokerList, &cfg)
group3, err := sarama.NewConsumerGroupFromClient(groupId, newClient3)
```

In this testing, we can see each consumer group with a new client, the result indicates that each consumer will consume a partition, which accord with expection.

So, How I can implement multiple consumer groups bind the same kafka client, rather than creating a new client per consumer group?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the recommended way to run multiple consumers. Compile one Go app with only one consumer. Run three processes instead. They will rebalance by using the same consumer group, but they will no longer not block one another within the same process.

Comment: Yes, @OneCricketeer, when I run 3 processes instead, it works ok, but there are 3 kafka clients, right? If there are 100+ consumers in the same group, similar like it will create 100+ kafka clients. We intended to create only one kafka client the group's consumers originally.

Comment: And why is that a problem? That's the recommended way to do it. For example, starting 100 pods in Kubernetes is just one value change in a ReplicaSet. Otherwise, yes, run one process, and it'll consume up to 100 partitions... But that's a single point of failure, and notice I said "up to", meaning it's not guaranteed to read anything, depending on overhead of reading other partitions

Comment: Thanks OneCricketeer for your reply. I may not understand clearly about what you said last: "But that's a single point of failure, and notice I said "up to", meaning it's not guaranteed to read anything, depending on overhead of reading other partitions " —— is that mean even if I create 100+ clients in the same process, it will not affect the performance? I look up some  information, it seems that we should not share one client with multiple consumers in consumer group. What I worried about is if I create many sarama.Client objects will consume too many resources.

Comment: I never said it would not impact performance. I said it was a single point of failure contained to one process